# if(isset($_GET['w'])&&$_GET['w']>=0&&$_GET['w']<=65) not working as it should

Tags: php

```
   if(isset($_GET['w'])&&$_GET['w']>=0&&$_GET['w']<=65)
```

when `$_GET['w']` has a value of (for example) `ccc` the condition becomes true whereas it should only accepts numbers from and including `0` to and including `65`

Comment: Could you give a bit more details on this? What are you trying to do here? Are those 0 .. 65 supposed to be numeral values?

Comment: http://domain/blabla/browse.php?az=1&w=ccc
this `ccc` value should be not accepted but it's somehow!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ccc" == 0 is true.

You should also check whether it is a number before comparing $_GET[...] parameters this way.

isnumeric() if I'm correct.

There are other tests you can use to check whether it's a decimal number. For example, you could run a `preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_GET['w']) == 1`.

Comment: I agree with Alexis. Regular expression should easily take care of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare a string to a number PHP will treat the string as being equal to zero, so it would be equal to zero and less than 65. You probably want to use is_integer() as well to make sure it's an integer.

Answer (score -1):

$_GET is "submitted" as text. If "text" is not empty, it is == 1. So your condition matches. To avoid this, first make sure you format "w" to an integer value/variable.

Comment: No. Strings are equal to zero. If you cast to boolean, they are also considered equal to TRUE if not empty.

Comment: Yeah, might be. Anyway it matches >=0 here then.